# summarise function is not grouping the data by groups when used with group_by()

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I have a large dataset with COVID-19 cases, with number of cases per for each date.This data is in the dat dataframe. I am trying to summarize these data by a variable which contains ID of all districts and the date variable (Meldedatum), for some reason the output in new data frame is just 1 row with total cases for the entire period and it is not grouped by ID and date variable. I dot know why that is. I am adding screen shot of the dataset to show what it looks like. Can someone help?

sample of data. There are more than 100,000 observations in total for 44 districts, I am just including sample with 2 different districts and dates.

```r
dat<-data.frame(Landkreis=c("Sk Stuttgart", "Sk Stuttgart", "Lk Freiburg","Lk Freiburg"),
              Anzahlfall=c(1,1,1,1),AnzahlTodesfall=c(0,1,2,1),
          Meldedatum=c("09-03-2020","18-03-2020","09-03-2020","20-03-2020"),IdLandkreis=c(8111, 8111,8116,8116))
```

[image]

```
datAggMelde <- dat %>% group_by(IdLandkreis,  Meldedatum) %>%
  summarize(sumCount = sum(AnzahlFall, na.rm = TRUE),
            sumDeath = sum(AnzahlTodesfall, na.rm = TRUE),
            Landkreis = first(Landkreis) )
```

Comment: Sorry for that inconvenience. Will no happen again.

Comment: One reason could be a nameclash with the `plyr` package. Try with `dplyr::summarize` to check that.

Comment: Please include a sample of `dat` in your question. The best way is using `dput(head(dat))`.

Comment: I included sample of the observations, and yes I considered the summarize vs summarise. That does not make a difference.

Comment: Sorry, I made syntax error in sharing the code for the dataframe. I have changed it now.´, it should work now.

Comment: There is a spelling error in the example data: I think it should say `AnzahlFall` (as in the code below). After fixing that I was not able to reproduce your problem (output has 4 rows, grouped by Id and date...) -> Please make sure you can reproduce the error you are describing with the information/data you are providing here

Comment: FYI, there are two potential "name" issues, and I'm not certain you are dealing with the correct one. *Within* `dplyr`, there are two similarly-named functions, `summarize` and `summarise`. They are the same function, spelled differently depending on which dialect of the English language one prefers (similar to `ggplot2::scale_color_*` and `_colour_`). This is not a problem and will never produce different code based on the spelling. However, there also exists the same two functions within the `plyr` package, *and they produce different results*. What you describe sounds like this second one.

Comment: To fix the second one (and/or to verify that it is or is not the culprit), you must be specific with which summarize you are trying to use: please try `dat %>% group_by(...) %>% dplyr::summarize(...)`, [edit] your question to reflect that specific change, and describe what is wrong with the output if it does not resolve the issue.

Comment: So, solution from r2evans has worked, I used dplyr::summarise instead of just summarise, but is I am a bit confused as to why this made the difference. I already had installed the dplyr library. But the issue is resolved. Thank you to everyone who contributed and helped me. :)